# Installing AJAX Toolkit on Visual Studio 2008

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008

When I'm installing AJAX Toolkit to my visual studio 2008 asp.net C#, and I'm using the tag:

```asp
<asp:ModalPopupExtender TargetControlID="btnYes" ID="pnlModal_ModalPopupExtender"
    runat="server" DynamicServicePath="" Enabled="True" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground"
    PopupControlID="pnlModal" CancelControlID="btnClose" DropShadow="true">
</asp:ModalPopupExtender>
```

I get:

> The tag is not recognized.

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you've already added the library (DLL) to your project, add `<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>` at the top of your ASPX page.

Comment: thank you, but i still have 1 problem, when i hover my mouse to the panel, there is no smart tag that appears... do you know why is that so? i am using visual studio 2008 by the way...

Comment: @bryan: To help you any further, we'll need more info about your setup, what you've tried, file structure, page code, etc.